# LibreCAD. New versions

Tags: development, cad

I am user of LibreCAD and I haven't seen any new version of it since June last year. But the new versions continue to release. These versions are for Windows and Mac. LibreCAD web page still says that the application is produced for the three OSes (including Linux) that makes me a bit confused.
Does any one know what happened to LibreCAD for Linux? They don't reply to the people who ask them about this on their blog. On sourceforge one can download the distro only for Win and Mac. Any idea?

Comment: Have you downloaded LibreCAD from the Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: Yes, I have. The version of it in Trusty repo is 2.0.2. I added ppa:librecad-dev/librecad-stable — there was 2.0.4 version. Daily repo had the same version of LibreCAD. Then using a manpage on their website I just built the last 2.0.7 version (as they suggested on their blog — they replied recently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- LibreCad in 13.10 has a 2.0.0~rc2+nolibs version in the repos.
- Ubuntu before that had a 1.0.2+nolibs version in the repos.
- 14.+ does not have a package in the repos.

Looking around on launchpad and the web I found a PPA.

- Install the latest version (works in 14.+) with:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:librecad-dev/librecad-daily
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install librecad
  ```

  Version it will install is 2.0.4 (and this will update itself when a new update is available) but it is not in the Ubuntu repositories anymore. It looks like they pulled the packages and created their own PPA.
- And this 2.0.4 version was updated [11 hours ago](https://launchpad.net/~librecad-dev/+archive/ubuntu/librecad-daily) and the one before that 22 weeks (5,6 months roughly so that is about the time you saw the last update before this).

So your worries were correct but have been solved 11 hours ago.

Comment: They have two PPAs. One of them is in your answer, the other is ppa:librecad-dev/librecad-stable. The last stable version is 2.0.7 and somehow it appears in daily PPA. Stable PPA does not contain the last stable version =) About the Ubuntu repos: I found LibreCAD on (https://packages.ubuntu.com) for Trusty (2.0.2), Utopic and Vivid (2.0.4). So I think it's OK with it.

Answer (score 0):

On their blog there is an answer to my question. Here it is:

> For Ubuntu we need to wait until it’s in PPA, usually that goes relative fast be we don’t fully control this process.
>
> Fortunately, building on Ubuntu is relative painless.

And

> Historically we don’t provide Linux build and we leave that up to the distro’s to take care of building this.
>
> If you want latest on Linux and you cannot wait for your disto to provide you a version then you need to compile this yourself.
>
> We have this page : http://librecad.org/cms/home/from-source/linux.html which isn’t always up to date, but also take a look at the supplied readme.

The reason was that Linux was not their favorite operating system. But if you want to have the latest version of their program you can easily build it from sources. There is a manpage on their website. All the steps are well described.

Everybody thank for help!